# Javascript lambda function does not see variable from parent scope

Tags: javascript, lambda, scope, anonymous-function

I have a code like:

```
$(function () {

    var addUserUrl = 'some string from the app';

    $('.select2').on('change', function() {
        console.log( addUserUrl );
        // Next line is the problem because of redefinition of var
        var addUserUrl = addUserUrl.replace(/idHolder/, $(this).val();
    });

});
```

and as I see **addUserUrl** in **onChange** callback is **undefined**. I am little confused. The scope of lambda function is the same as scope of addUserUrl in my opinion. Can somebody explain me please what happens there?

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript; the code won't parse, and so cannot run: `var addUserUrl = {link addUser! id => 'idHolder'};`. If it weren't for that, the event callback would access `addUserUrl` just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2wqeyL7t/

Comment: I am sorry thi is only example. I'll fix it.

Comment: The code in your edit will work just fine (see my edited comment above, we crossed paths :-) ).

Comment: I would suggest making a snippet of this example to see if you can reproduce the problem — as it is, it works just fine for me.

Comment: I have it. This code works fine. But in my original code lambda contains a line with ```var addUserUrl = addUserUrl.replace(/idHolder/, id);``` which redefine the variable.

Comment: Using `var addUserUrl` in the inner function _hides_ the variable of the outer scope. So just use another variable name in the inner function: `var updatedAddUserUrl = addUserUrl.replace(/idHolder/, id)`